# Polynomial division algorithm

Tags: python, sage

I'm using sage and was trying to implement univariate polynomial division with the pseudocode given by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division#Pseudocode).

But I think it is stuck looping, for example if I ask `div(x^2-1,x-1)` it doesn't give the immediate answer. It should return `(0,x+1)` but it does nothing.

The code:

```
def div(p,q):   
    if q==0:
        return("NaN")
    elif q!=0:
        l=0
        r=p
        while r!=0 and q.degree()<=r.degree():
            t=(r.leading_coefficient())/(q.leading_coefficient())
            l=l+t
            r=r-(t*q)
        return(l,r)
```

**Edit:** I was reading the pseudocode wrong and missed that I was not reducing the degree of my polynomial so clearly it just was doing nothing. I 'fixed it' but now it is giving me some new error but I think it's some coercion error.

Any help is appreciated!

The new code:

```
def div(p,q):
    if q==0:
        return("NaN")
    elif q!=0:
        l=0
        r=p
        while r!=0 and q.degree()<=r.degree():
            t=r.leading_coefficient()/q.leading_coefficient()
            m=x^r.degree()/x^q.degree()
            l=l+t*m
            r=r-(t*m*q)
            print(l,r) #To see when the code fails
        return(l,r)
```

**Edit 2:** Upon inspection of ["Polynomials in sage"](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/tutorial/tour_polynomial.html) it says that if you divide two polynomials then it coerces it to an element of the fraction field which would give me an error in the r.degree() line. Anyone knows a workaround to this?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please provide your code in the form of a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) such that we can try it, play with it and be able to give you answer more easily

Comment: Hey @JanStránský, upon revision of my code, in my opinion is within the guidelines for [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is there anything you see that is not correct?

Comment: If I copy/paste your code in a .py file and run the .py file, it does nothing (it is just function definition). Please put there an example how you call it, which should reproduce your problem

Comment: I think you need to replace 'l' by 'q: l=0 to q=0 and l=l+t to q=q+t. Otherwise the 'q' condition on the while doesn't change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by casting m into the base ring, m=R(m) I guess this is some sloppy patch I would like to know if there is some smarter way to make this algorithm.
The fixed code:

```
x=var('x')
R.<x>=PolynomialRing(QQ)

def div(p,q):
    if q==0:
        return("NaN")
    elif q!=0:
        l=0
        r=p
        while r!=0 and q.degree()<=r.degree():
            t=r.leading_coefficient()/q.leading_coefficient()
            m=x^r.degree()/x^q.degree()
            m=R(m)
            l=l+t*m
            r=r-(t*m*q)
            print(l,r)
        return(l,r)
```

Comment: The line `x = var('x')` is not needed. The next line `R.<x> = ...` redefines `x` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

In Sage

- `p / q` gives a result in the fraction field
- `p // q` gives the quotient in the ring (dropping any remainder)
- `p % q` gives the remainder
- `p.quo_rem(q)` gives the pair `(quotient, remainder)` at once